# Tool to share build path or apk in android

Tags: android

I faced one interview where they asked, how you share you build path or apk to others. You are directly giving apk to them or you are using any tool?

One of the answer is Alpha/beta testing which is provided by google store.

Is there any other tool also?

Comment: There are many tools available. Go with [http://testfairy.com/](http://testfairy.com/) or TestFlight

Comment: @MD...thanx ... but this is not a tool ....as I checked this side upload the apk and then send link to the person to download the apk..
we can send directly to the person instead of using this website.
this site provide extra thing which is community page..

Comment: @VV Then what is Alpha and Beta Testing?

Comment: in alpha and beta testing ... you will directly install application from google play store if your google id is in the testing group, no need to give apk

Answer (score 0):

TestFlight remove the support of Android applications, but Crashlytics have a Beta distribution tool too http://try.crashlytics.com/